# How can I get a list of IP addresses that connected to an Apache server?

Tags: linux, command-line, apache-http-server, ip

I'm trying to get a list of IP addresses that have connected to the Apache server in the past week for port 80, port 22 (the port FTP uses?), and whatever the port ssh/ putty uses. What is the command line prompt for it? I found this here http://www.mickgenie.com/how-to-check-apache-connections/ but the last example just returns a 1.

I also found this:

http://linuxboxadmin.com/micro-howtos/system-administration/monitoring-apache-connections.html

The problem with that though is it is listing current and established connections. I would like to get past and past established connections.

Comment: Your question is probably being downvoted because it seems like you're trying to do something that is pretty advanced for your experience level, and are describing it with jargon that's not completely consistent. But +1 for trying, and for asking, and welcome to SU!

Answer (score 1):

There's no one universal log location, and you're probably going to have to process your logs with the right tools to get the information you need. The magic of oldschool linux tools is they are *all* textfiles so stuff like sed/awk/cut/sort will save you tons of time getting the data you need

`/var/log/` is a great place to start looking. I don't *personally* run apache, and my servers are relatively low use so I don't really log lighttpd, but according to this [U&L post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored) `/var/log/apache2/access.log` is the place to look

As for ssh, I *do* know where it is - its in [/var/log/auth.log](https://serverfault.com/questions/130482/how-to-check-sshd-log), just use grep to select out lines with sshd.

In *general* configuration files, and documentation is the best place to start in order to check if you are logging at all, and where those logs are.

Comment: thank you for the help. I look into the auth.log file and then I look up an ip address here (https://db-ip.com/172.31.7.74). there is says "Warning! This is not a valid IP address on the Internet because it belongs to a private network. It does not identify a unique destination as it is only meant to be used inside local area networks"

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918 . That's exactly what they are. If you're *certain* they arn't RFC1918 addresses. something else is fishy. [Maybe spoofing](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13360/ingress-rfc1918-spoofing-how-to-handle-it)

Answer (score 0):

Successful http connections may be logged by Apache in a file like /var/log/apache2/access.log. That file may get rotated by something like logrotate to access.log.0, access.log.1.gz, etc.

FTP connections may similarly be logged by the ftp server, maybe even someone in /var/log.

SSH sessions are probably logged, but perhaps in /var/log/syslog, messages, auth, or secure.

In summary, the connections are most likely to be logged in /var/log/, by the particular service handling them. The particular commands to run will depend on a) which services are running, b) what files they logged to, c) what format they used, and d) what date ranges you want.

I would recommend spending some time with `less`, `zless`, and `grep` in /var/log/ and ask additional questions once you have specific file parsing or command invocation obstacles to overcome.

Comment: thank you for the help. I look into the auth.log file and then I look up an ip address here (https://db-ip.com/172.31.7.74). there is says "Warning! This is not a valid IP address on the Internet because it belongs to a private network. It does not identify a unique destination as it is only meant to be used inside local area networks"?